# Show that $D_4$ is isomorphic to the direct product of two cyclic groups of order 2.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, dihedral-groups

What I have tried is the following:

Since $D_4$ is a group of order four, then it is abelian, so we use the fundamental theorem of abelian groups which tells us that every finite abelian group is isomorphic to the direct product of cyclic groups. Therefore, $D_4$ has two options. The first is to be isomorphic to a cyclic group of order 4 (but since the elements of $D_4$ do not form a cyclic group, this case is ruled out) or to be isomorphic to the direct product of two cyclic groups of order two, since the other is ruled out possibility, then this is the case.

Assuming my proof was correct, is there another way to prove it?

*EDITED:*

Considering in $S_Z$ the permutations given by $σ_o(n)=n+1$ and $τ_o(n)=−n$.We define the infinite dihedral group as $D_\infty=<σ_o,τ_o>$. Then we define $D_{2n}=D_\infty/<σ_o^n>$. Considering $σ=σ_oN_n$ and $τ=τ_oN_n$ where $N_n=<σ_o^n>$. Then $D_{2n}=<σ,τ>=\{1,σ,...,σ^{n−1},τ,στ,...σ^{n−1}τ\}$. Considering this definition and my initial question, the value of $n$ will be 2, that is $D_{2*2}=D_4$

Comment: You can simply define an isomorphism to $\mathbb{Z_2}\times\mathbb{Z_2}$. It's a basic exercise in group theory that there are only two groups of order $4$ up to isomorphism, usually you see this special case long before you get to the fundamental theorem of abelian groups.

Comment: How do you define dihedral groups?

Comment: We consider in $S_\mathbb Z$ the permutations given by $σ_o(n) = n+ 1$ and $τ_o (n) = −n$.We define the infinite dihedral group as $D_\infty = <\sigma_o,\tau_o>$

Then we define $D_{2n} = D_\infty/ <\sigma_o^n>$. Considering $σ = σ_oN_n$ and $τ = τ_oN_n$ where $N_n=<\sigma_o^n>$. Then $D_{2n}=<\sigma,\tau>$. Then $D_{2n} = \{1, σ, . . . , σ^{n−1}
, τ, στ, . . . σ^{n−1}τ\}$.

Comment: Thank you, @MenuPrincipal. I suggest you [edit] the question to include those details. Not everyone checks the comments.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice , I have modified my question. I hope it can be better understood.